# No action when submit button is clicked, but it should register a user

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I am trying to create a simple registration and login system. When I am trying to register a user I am providing all informations to the input such as username, password and confirmpassword, but when I hit the submit button it redirect me to the /login even it should to /welcome page as I declared in the controller. When I added a simple debug in the controller in the specific mapping, nothing happened I suppose that the method is not even executed, could someone take a look at this code and tell me what is wrong here?

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, SecurityService securityService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
//        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
//
        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password")
                               String password, @RequestParam("confirmPassword") String confirmPassword,
                               Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        User foundUser = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (foundUser != null) {
            model.addAttribute("msgError", "That user already exists");
            return "registration";
        }

        if (username.equals("") || username.length() < 2) {
            model.addAttribute("msgError", "Wrong username");
            return "registration";
        }

        if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            model.addAttribute("msgError", "Passwords can not be different");
            return "registration";
        }

        User user = new User(request.getParameter("username"), request.getParameter("password"), request.getParameter("confirmPassword"));

        securityService.autoLogin(username, password);

        userService.addUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("msgSuccess", "User registered successfully");
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("msgError", "Your username and password is invalid");
        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("msgError", "You have been logged out successfully");

        return "login";
    }
}
```

And the JSP for the registration is as below

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Watchers - Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="registration" class="sign-form">
            <h2 class="sign-form-heading">Create an new account</h2>
            <p><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="confirmPassword" /></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because of your forms `action`-value.

try to prepare the action value with spring's taglib
in this example its got the prefix `spring`

```
<spring:url value="/registration" var="url"/>
<form method="POST" action="${url}" class="sign-form">
```

**Edit:**

referring to your comment, i've got to ask a few questions:

how do you protect/secure your web-app, with spring-security or security-constraints in web.xml?

is the `/registration`-path also protected/secured? if it is and if your login-config refers to `/login`, you will be redirected to `/login`

Comment: unfortunately no, it does not help.